# Scrape Div's content loading dynamically via ajax using Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, html, ajax, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want scrape data from other website page which loading table's data dynamically.
I am using Php and Simple Html Dom for scraping after searching lot did not find any solutions how to scrape dynamic data from web page? Or there is another way to do this?

## I have to scrape table data from this url->https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/leagues/standings/313/classic.

## I am using below code to do this.

```
$url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/leagues/standings/313/classic";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$html->find('div#ismr-classic-standings');
foreach($html->find('table.ism-table--standings tr') as $row){
//But count($row)=0 due to late loading html in table.
}
```

Comment: Even though table's data is dynamic, the DOM structure should be the same. Is it same ? if so then you can find by using its class, or html DOM structure. Can you add some code so that we better understand.

Comment: add some code or example so we can go further!!

Comment: Hello, @Mit.agile code added

Comment: so basically, you need all the records which is inside **<table class="ism-table ism-table--standings">** table ?

Comment: I need href value under Team and Manager column

Comment: i found interesting, can you do this **echo file_get_html('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/leagues/standings/313/classic')->plaintext;**

Comment: m unable to see table contents using above code.

Comment: It will not fetch because its loading dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121587/discussion-between-mit-agile-and-shashank-singh).

Comment: You can either run it through phantomjs, or try to catch the json data that's coming from the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is calling another link and retrieving JSON data; try this code:

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$MyWebsite = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/leagues-classic-standings/313?phase=1&le-page=1&ls-page=1';
$html = file_get_html($MyWebsite);
$JSON_value = json_decode($html, true);
$results = $JSON_value['standings']['results'];

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo    $result['entry_name'] . '->' . $result['event_total'] . '<br/>';
}
```